# I tried to open other View Controller in custom Cell Clas on action of Button Tapped but I got this error; check error in link: what Method should I

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols

```
  @IBAction func selectCrypto(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // viewModel.walletApiData()
        openWalletPopUP()
   
    } 
}
```

-: **openwalletListPopup**

```
extension SelectCoinCell {
    
    func openWalletPopUP() {
    
       let walletpopup = WalletListPopUP.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Crypto)
       walletpopup.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
         walletpopup.descriptionLbl.text = (LocalizedString.selectCryptoWallet.localized)
    
       self.present(walletpopup , animated: false)
    
    } 
}
```

[you can see error by click link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7PX5.png)

Comment: Your class `SelectCoinCell` does not have the method `present(...)`. You probably want to use your viewcontroller for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should present from a UIViewController, not from a UITableViewCell.

Try This:

```
class SelectCoinCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var didTapAction: (() -> ())? = nil
    
    @IBAction func selectCrypto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        didTapAction?()
    }
}


class MyViewContoller: UIViewController{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectCoinCell", for: indexPath) as? SelectCoinCell
        cell?.didTapAction = { [weak self] in
            self?.openWalletPopUP()
        }
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension MyViewContoller {
    
    func openWalletPopUP() {
        let walletpopup = WalletListPopUP.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Crypto)
        walletpopup.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        walletpopup.descriptionLbl.text = (LocalizedString.selectCryptoWallet.localized)
        self.present(walletpopup , animated: false)
        
    }
}
```